# Typescript types of composition Ramda lens with React useState set function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, functional-programming, event-handling, ramda.js

I am learning FP and I am trying to figure out how to handle events in react.
For example, let's use following scenario:

```js
interface Todo {
    task: string
    done: boolean
}

interface TodoProps {
    todo: Todo
    onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>
}

function TodoItem({todo, onChange}: TodoProps) {
    return (
        <label>
            {todo.task}
            <input type="checkbox" checked={todo.done} onChange={onChange}/>
        </label>
    )
}

function App() {
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState({
        task: "Some task",
        done: false
    });

    const toggleTodo = // I need to implement this

    return (
        <main>
            <TodoItem onChange={toggleTodo} todo={todo}/>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Nothing fancy, just basic todo app.
In the missing function I need to create object with updated `done` property. To do that I create Ramda's lens focused on `done` property.

```js
const doneLens = lensProp('done');
```

Then it should be easy to finish the goal. All I need is to compose `setTodo` with Rambda's `over`.

```js
const toggleDone = () => compose(setTodo, over(doneLens, toggleBoolean))(todo)
```

**But here is the issue**. I am getting this ts error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   
  The last overload gave the following error.     
    Argument of type '<T>(value: T) => T' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x0: unknown, x1: unknown, x2: unknown) => SetStateAction<{ task: string; done: boolean; }>'.       
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<{ task: string; done: boolean; }>'.         
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(prevState: { task: string; done: boolean; }) => { task: string; done: boolean; }'.
```

In pure js this function should work, but ts can't infer return type of `over` function. It's logical. The `over` is generic so let's try to add explicit type.

```js
const toggleDone = () => compose(setTodo, over<Todo>(doneLens, toggleBoolean))(todo)
```

And I get:

```
TS2554: Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.  
  index.d.ts(669, 51): An argument for 'value' was not provided.

TS2769: No overload matches this call.   
  The last overload gave the following error.     
    Argument of type 'Todo' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x0: unknown, x1: unknown, x2: unknown) => SetStateAction<{ task: string; done: boolean; }>'.       
      Type 'Todo' provides no match for the signature '(x0: unknown, x1: unknown, x2: unknown): SetStateAction<{ task: string; done: boolean; }>'.
```

Ramda functions are curried by default, but if I can read the error correctly it seem that when I add explicit type then the currying does not working.

I can come up with workaround:

```
const overDone: (t: Todo) => Todo = over(doneLens, toggleBoolean);
const toggleDone = () => compose(setTodo, overDone)(todo);
```

This works because return type of `overDone` match with input type of `setTodo`.

But, my question is. How to fix the oneliner?
Or if you know better way to handle similar scenarios with lenses, function composition, useState hook and typescript I am curious to see so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the type `Todo` to the `lensProp` call. You can also move it out of the component, because you don't need to generate the function whenever the component re-renders:

```
const doneLens = lensProp<Todo>("done");
const toggleDone = over(doneLens, not);
```

Since `setTodo` is a function that can call another function (see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to which it passes the current `todo`, you don't need `R.compose`:

```
const toggleTodo = () => setTodo(over(doneLens, not));
```

And this how your component would look ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-ramda-forked-qqt0r?file=/src/index.tsx)):

```
const doneLens = lensProp<Todo>("done");
const toggleDone = over(doneLens, not);

function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState({
    task: "Some task",
    done: false
  });

  const toggleTodo = () => setTodo(toggleDone);
    
  return (
    <main>
      <TodoItem onChange={toggleTodo} todo={todo} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

A simpler option would be to use `R.evolve` ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-ramda-forked-6nc44?file=/src/index.tsx)):

```
const toggleDone = evolve({ done: not });

function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState({
    task: "Some task",
    done: false
  });

  const toggleTodo = () => setTodo(toggleDone);

  console.log(todo);

  return (
    <main>
      <TodoItem onChange={toggleTodo} todo={todo} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: The `R.evolve` is pretty handy I didn't knew about. But I still have issue with the `compose`. I know that I don't need it in this case, but I give this just as example and I can imagine more complex scenarios where it could be useful to use it. The issue is that when i write `lensProp<Todo>` the IDE yells at me: `TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1` (it underlines the generic argument). Also when I try to compose `evolve` I get TS error (add generic argument doesn't help). The main reason I wrote this question was the type issue within `compose`.

Comment: I haven't encountered the issue with the compose in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-ramda-forked-d4ri2?file=/src/index.tsx). What version of Ramda and `@types/ramda` are you using?

Comment: `"@types/ramda": "^0.27.60",` and I create project with `yarn create vite` choose react with ts and don't modify config at all

Comment: Here is a working sandbox using your original code. As you can see TS works fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-ramda-forked-neu64?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was wondering for a quite long time why on my local machine I have ts errors and in sandbox the same code works well. Then I realize that when I installed `ramda` I misspelled and install `ramBda`. Now after reinstall everything works just fine.